# CSS3 hover on/off effects in Chrome skip animation

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

So my hover effect works just fine in every browser including IE9+ and it does work in Chrome except hovering on/off the element in certain places can make it skip the animation and snap straight back to the starting positing instead of fading slowly.

This only happens with Chrome, is it a bug, or is there something I can add in my code to smooth things out for Chrome and make sure it always animates back to the default state instead of just jumping to it.

Its using an image with the following class attached to it, the image is also using shape-outside to form text around it so i've included all the CSS code below - the animation slightly rotates and tilts the device picture on hover.

```
.floatleft {
    float:left;
    width: 240px;
    height: 341px;
    -webkit-shape-outside: url(http://url.com/image.png);
    -o-shape-outside: url(http://url.com/image.png);
    shape-outside: url(http://url.com/image.png);
    -webkit-shape-image-threshold: 0.5;
    -o-shape-image-threshold: 0.5;
    shape-image-threshold: 0.5;
    -webkit-shape-margin: 20px;
    -o-shape-margin: 20px;
    shape-margin: 20px;
    margin:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    }

.floatleft:hover, .floatleft:active
{
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(-13deg) rotate(-5deg);
    transform:rotateX(-13deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -o-transform:rotateX(-13deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateX(-13deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateX(-13deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Heres the Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/d5wnnqfd/

Comment: Can you post a Codepen link or something so we can test with exactly the right code?

Comment: I can't reproduce it from your fiddle...can you give more specific instructions about how to trigger it?

Comment: Hi Ben, just mouseover the image, it should animate fine in Safari, Firefox etc - on Chrome it animates but if you mouse away from certain areas like the corners of the picture, instead of smoothly animating back to its original position it will just snap back into position instantly. Its a little harder to recreate in the fiddle but you can try hovering over the bottom right corner of the phone picture and then move the mouse outside of the browser, it'll sometimes snap back.